# how to import library and use it in all store files nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

im using nuxtjs and i want import library one time and access it on any store file like

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

thank you

Comment: Rrad about nuxt plugins

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign that library to the store instance.

Then you can access it with "this" keyword from actions and - if not mistaken - mutations as well